# Invitation to friends to ask for liking fanpage

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, dialog, invitation

How to use Facebook API to send invitations to friends to ask for a specific fanpage like.

And the other question.

How then show a list of users who have sent an invitation with an indication of how many people liked the profile. In this way, users will take a ranking of who sent the most invitations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to use Facebook API to send invitations to friends to ask for a specific fanpage like.

You may use the [Notification API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-notifications/), with a message and the link to page. Or, using the [Feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) dialog by posting on wall to each of the app user. (I prefer the first one)

> How then show a list of users who have sent an invitation with an indication of how many people liked the profile. In this way, users will take a ranking of who sent the most invitations

The invitations will be sent to all the friends I guess. If not, then you have to keep the record of the invitations sent, manually.

Comment: manually is ok But I like it when you click, you can call a callback. I like to assign it to a specific user.